# Analyzing crashdumps from crosscompiled linux target

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, cross-compiling

I am facing a problem with the analysis of an crashdump that was generated on a linux machine I do not have access to. The situation looks like the following:

- Development happens on Linux machines running distributions like Ubuntu 14.04, 13.10 and 14.04.
- The target is an embedded x86 based System that runs on a stripped
  down Debian 5
- The build for the target happens on one of the development machines, dependent on who does the release. We use a chroot-environment to do the cross-build and we are pretty sure the chroot-environments are the same (revision controlled via git)

By the Way, the software is written in C++.

Now from time to time the software crashes in a situation we cannot reproduce so our users send us an core-file via email. The plan looks like the following:

- Compile the same version of the software with debug-symbols from within the chroot-environment
- Look at the core-file with GDB, also inside the chroot-environment.

This normally works fine, except for one problem. It only works if debugging happens on the same machine the stripped and the released binary was build on. On other machines, the debugger seems to get confused, a stacktrace may consist of completely unrelated calls that do not make any sense. This is a thing we are wondering about for some time now without a conclusion. Also it was a situation we could deal with easily.

But then some mindless upgrading to a new distribution took place on my machine, rendering all the core files from targets that I did the build for useless...

Now I am looking for a way to (a) understand what is happening and (b) for a way to cross-debug core files that where generated on machines without the possibility of remote access that run different Linux distributions. Oh and (c) if we maybe are doing something fundamentally wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It only works if debugging happens on the same machine the stripped and the released binary was build on.
>   (a) understand what is happening

It's pretty obvious that despite your belief that you have a hermetic build environment, you *in fact don't*. If you did have a completely hermetic build environment, building on a different machine wouldn't matter.

Therefore, your first step should be to find and eliminate everything non-hermetic, until you can build *bit-identical* releases on every one of the machines you are building your releases on.

Once you have achieved that, it should also solve your (b) problem.

> (c) if we maybe are doing something fundamentally wrong?

What you appear to be doing fundamentally wrong is that you trust that your chroot is version-controlled, when it appears to clearly not be.

Comment: Found it! Thanks for pointing in the right direction. The Project is compiled by a makefile that does in an early stage look up all the objects that need to be compiled by invoking `find`. It turns out that all the objects are compiled bit-identical on all the machines I could test on. But as `find` does not return its results in a guaranteed order, the order in which the objects are handed over to the linker is not always the same. Piping the `find` results through `sort` solves the problem. On all machines available for testing the build results are bit-identical now.